# How to detect if a RepositionThemeTransition is completed or force a RepositionThemeTransition to activate

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a ListView where the entire ListView would slide to left and reload the Listivew if user clicks an item. The problem is if I do both of these tasks in a button click event handler, the transition would not render until the method has finished. And thus the ListView transition would not even be animated since I reload the ItemSources immediately afterwards. I need something that can await the ListView transition and then reloads listview or forces the ListView to activate its transition.

XAML:

```
       <ListView
            x:Name="DocumentListView"
            IsItemClickEnabled="True"
            ItemClick="FileClicked"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind Files, Mode=OneWay}"
            Loading="DocumentListView_Loading">
            <ListView.Transitions>
                <TransitionCollection>
                    <RepositionThemeTransition />
                </TransitionCollection>
            </ListView.Transitions>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:DocumentItem">
                    <local:DocumentsListRow />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

C#:

```
private void FileClicked(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    DocumentListView.Margin = new Thickness(-500, 0, 500, 0);
    DocumentListViewHeader.Margin = new Thickness(-500, 0, 500, 0);
    parent = Utility.Utility.FindParent<Documents>(this);

    //this line resets the ItemSource of ListView, if I include this the transition won't work
    parent.reloadList(0);
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're two choices for you.

1. You could add a little time delay after you change the ListView's position. See the following code sample:

   ```
   <Button Content="Remove Rectangle" Click="RemoveButton_Click"/>
   <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="rectangleItems">
       <ItemsControl.Transitions>
           <TransitionCollection>
               <RepositionThemeTransition></RepositionThemeTransition>
           </TransitionCollection>
       </ItemsControl.Transitions>
       <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
           <ItemsPanelTemplate>
               <WrapGrid Height="400"/>
           </ItemsPanelTemplate>
       </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
       <ItemsControl.Items>
           <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10"/>
           <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10"/>
           <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10"/>
           <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10"/>
           <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10"/>
           <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10"/>
           <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10"/>
           <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10"/>
           <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10"/>
       </ItemsControl.Items>
   </ItemsControl>
   ```

```cs
    private async void RemoveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        rectangleItems.Margin = new Thickness(100);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        rectangleItems.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            rectangleItems.Items.Add(new Rectangle() { Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow), Width = 100, Height = 100, Margin = new Thickness(10) });
        }
    }
```

2. You could use the [RepositionThemeAnimation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.RepositionThemeAnimation), instead of RepositionThemeTransition. The RepositionThemeAnimation has [Completed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.RepositionThemeAnimation#events) event. You could reload the list in the Completed event handler.

   ```
   <Grid>
   <Grid.Resources>
       <Storyboard x:Name="PositionStoryboard">
           <RepositionThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rectangleItems" Duration="0:0:1" FromHorizontalOffset="-400" Completed="RepositionThemeAnimation_Completed"/>
       </Storyboard>
   </Grid.Resources>
   <Button Content="Remove Rectangle" Click="RemoveButton_Click"/>
   <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="rectangleItems">
       <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
           <ItemsPanelTemplate>
               <WrapGrid Height="400"/>
           </ItemsPanelTemplate>
       </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
       <ItemsControl.Items>
           <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10"/>
           <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10"/>
           <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10"/>
           <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10"/>
           <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10"/>
           <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10"/>
           <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10"/>
           <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10"/>
           <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10"/>
       </ItemsControl.Items>
   </ItemsControl>
   </Grid>
   ```

```cs
    private  void RemoveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PositionStoryboard.Begin();
    }

    private void RepositionThemeAnimation_Completed(object sender, object e)
    {
        rectangleItems.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            rectangleItems.Items.Add(new Rectangle() { Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow), Width = 100, Height = 100, Margin = new Thickness(10) });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried the second option before but the RepositionThemeAnimation doesn't allow me to set the duration and it's too swift.